# How to import website completely source with iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In the iframe source code page i see just this code how can import all source original webpage css and js

```html
    <iframe src="https://morocco.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php"height="1500" width="1550"></iframe>
```

How to import website completely source with iFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the src field on the browser bar, and you will be viewing the real website, not an iframe mirror